# Android Realm Arraylist and simple POJO

Tags: java, android, arraylist, realm

guys i retrieve from outside database (using retrofit) many (6600 rows) of object which looks and works with my POJO class. After that i try to put it into Realm object but its very slow. I suspect that this slow action is because i begin i commit transaction row by row. Maybe anybody know how to put full arraylist to realm object in one commit?
My Main:

```
private class AsyncTaskRetro extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            PlacesAPI.Factory.getInstance().getPlaces().enqueue(new Callback<Places>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Places> call, Response<Places> response) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getPosts().size(); i++) {
                        RowModel rowModel = new RowModel(response.body().getPosts().get(i).getNazwa(),
                                Double.parseDouble(response.body().getPosts().get(i).getSzer()),
                                Double.parseDouble(response.body().getPosts().get(i).getDlug()));
                        rowModels.add(rowModel);
                    }
                    String oldName;
                    oldName = rowModels.get(0).getName();
                    shopsNames.add(rowModels.get(0).getName());


                    mRealm.beginTransaction();
                    RowModel rowModelRealm = mRealm.createObject(RowModel.class);
                    mRealm.commitTransaction();
                    for (int j = 0; j < rowModels.size(); j++) {
                        mRealm.beginTransaction();
                        rowModelRealm.setName(rowModels.get(j).getName());
                        rowModelRealm.setLattitude(rowModels.get(j).getLattitude());
                        rowModelRealm.setLongitude(rowModels.get(j).getLongitude());
                        mRealm.commitTransaction();

                        if (rowModels.get(j).getName().equals(oldName)) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        oldName = rowModels.get(j).getName();
                        shopsNames.add(rowModels.get(j).getName());
                    }



     //sortowanie 

listy z nazwami sklepow
                    Collections.sort(shopsNames);

                adapter = new ShopsAdapter(MainActivity.this, shopsNames);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Places> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

        return null;
    }
}
```

and POJO:

```
public class RowModel extends RealmObject {

    @Required
    private String name;
    @Required
    private Double lattitude, longitude;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getLattitude() {
        return lattitude;
    }

    public void setLattitude(Double lattitude) {
        this.lattitude = lattitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public RowModel(String name, Double lattitude, Double longitude) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lattitude = lattitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public RowModel() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) you're using Realm 0.82.2, and that version has quirks which is why the next stable version I recommend is 0.87.5; but in reality the **latest** stable version (at the moment) is 3.1.4.

You should probably switch to a version that isn't 2 years old?

2.) You are running an AsyncTask, but you use `enqueue` in it:

```
getPlaces().enqueue(new Callback<Places>() {    
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<Places> call, Response<Places> response) {
```

This means that Retrofit callback will execute on UI thread.

Then, you do synchronous transactions, so you're writing to Realm on the UI thread, which is bad.

3.) you're trying to manually sort the downloaded elements and then showing them in the adapter also manually, which doesn't make sense if you're using Realm, because Realm allows sorting elements by a particular field. Also `shopsNames` is definitely not a RealmResults, meaning you aren't even listening for changes made to the DB.

`ShopsAdapter` should be a `RealmBaseAdapter`.

---

So the code should be more like this

```
private class AsyncTaskRetro
        extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try(Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
            Response<Place> response = PlacesAPI.Factory.getInstance().getPlaces().execute();
            Place place = response.body();
            List<Post> posts = place.getPosts();
            r.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
                for(Post post : posts) {
                    RowModel rowModel = new RowModel(post.getNazwa(),
                            Double.parseDouble(post.getSzer()),
                            Double.parseDouble(post.getDlug()));
                    rowModels.add(rowModel);
                }
                String oldName;
                oldName = rowModels.get(0).getName();
                shopsNames.add(rowModels.get(0).getName());

                RowModel rowModelRealm = realm.createObject(RowModel.class);
                for(RowModel rowModel : rowModels) {
                    rowModelRealm.setName(rowModel.getName());
                    rowModelRealm.setLattitude(rowModel.getLattitude());
                    rowModelRealm.setLongitude(rowModel.getLongitude());

                    if(rowModel.getName().equals(oldName)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    oldName = rowModel.getName();
                    shopsNames.add(rowModel.getName());
                }
            });
            // no need to manually sort if you use RealmBaseAdapter with findAllSorted()
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now i use latest ver 3.2.1, change instance to init first and later use Realm.getDefaultinstance(); everything works fast and fine. Thank you guys!

Comment: There is a known bug in 3.2.1 that you need to add `-keepnames public class * extends io.realm.RealmObject` if you're using Proguard, but otherwise that also works

Answer (score 1):

a Realm object has the method:
    `insert(Iterable<E> objects)`
which should let you copy all of your `RowModel` objects in at once

Comment: it looks ok but how later put it into my POJO model Arraylist?

Comment: Why not just use a `RealmList` or `RealmResults` object? Both are collections, but if you really need the array list, then you can just create one from the `RealmList` object.

Assuming `rowModels` is your array list, just do `rowModels = new ArrayList<>(*your realm collection*)`

Comment: ok but problem is with pass this object to another activity. When i do this like RowModel rowModelRealm = mRealm.createObject(RowModel.class); i a can simple acces it in second activity by: Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);

        RealmResults<RowModel> rowModels = realm.where(RowModel.class).equalTo("name", "Tesco").findAll();

Comment: `Realm.getInstance(this);` means you're still using at most **Realm 0.82.2**. People won't be able to help you if you're using a 2 years old version, you should switch to **3.1.4** at least.